# Turnkey Windows app VNC in a box?

Tags: windows, vnc

There's one Windows app I would like to use across a VNC connection.  Otherwise I have no use for Windows.  The app does not work with Wine.

What is the simplest/most turnkey way of making a single Windows app available through VNC on the public net regardless of $$?  Either a fully-hosted solution or something I can run on my VPS.

Answer (score 4):

This is exactly what Windows Terminal Services was built for. No need for VNC. Performance and security are both better with RDP.

There are a *lot* of RDP vulnerability-scanning botnets out there, though, so make sure to have your server well-secured, use strong passwords, etc.

Comment: What about the turnkey aspect?  Is there a Xen image I can spin-up, log into, and install/use my windows app?